# InternalCompilerError: Compiled contract not found. Contracts are correctly pointed to

Tags: truffle, erc-20, crowdsale, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

**Environment**
OpenZeppelin 2.5.1
Truffle v5.2.4 (core: 5.2.4)
Node v15.11.0

**Details**

Inheriting the *PostDeliveryCrowdsale* into my crowdsale contract fails to compile as can be seen below, this only happens when using *PostDeliveryCrowdsale* and implementing it as per the documentation.

I'd like to be able to use PostDeliveryCrowdsale to hold the tokens until the crowdsale ends and have them distributed automatically. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
√ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
> Compiling .\contracts\MyCrowdsale.sol
√ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1

InternalCompilerError: Compiled contract not found.

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.2.4 (core: 5.2.4)
Node v15.11.0
```

**Code to reproduce**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/PostDeliveryCrowdsale.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/roles/CapperRole.sol";

contract OS_PRESALE is Crowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, CapperRole, Ownable, PostDeliveryCrowdsale {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _contributions;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _caps;

    

    uint256 private _individualDefaultCap;

        constructor(

        uint256 rate,            // rate, in TKNbits

        address payable wallet,  // wallet to send Ether

        //address tokenWallet,     // address holding the tokens

        IERC20 token,            // the token

        uint256 cap,             // total cap, in wei

        uint256 individualCap,   // individual cap in wei

        uint256 openingTime,     // opening time in unix epoch seconds

        uint256 closingTime      // closing time in unix epoch seconds

    )

        public

        PostDeliveryCrowdsale()

        CappedCrowdsale(cap)

        TimedCrowdsale(openingTime, closingTime)

        Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token)

        

    {

          _individualDefaultCap = individualCap;

    }

    /**

     * @dev Sets a specific beneficiary's maximum contribution.

     * @param beneficiary Address to be capped

     * @param cap Wei limit for individual contribution

     */

    function setCap(address beneficiary, uint256 cap) external onlyCapper {

        _caps[beneficiary] = cap;

    }

    /**

     * @dev Returns the cap of a specific beneficiary.

     * @param beneficiary Address whose cap is to be checked

     * @return Current cap for individual beneficiary

     */

    function getCap(address beneficiary) public view returns (uint256) {

        uint256 cap = _caps[beneficiary];

        if (cap == 0) {

            cap = _individualDefaultCap;

        }

        return cap;

    }

    /**

     * @dev Returns the amount contributed so far by a specific beneficiary.

     * @param beneficiary Address of contributor

     * @return Beneficiary contribution so far

     */

    function getContribution(address beneficiary) public view returns (uint256) {

        return _contributions[beneficiary];

    }

    /**

     * @dev Extend parent behavior requiring purchase to respect the beneficiary's funding cap.

     * @param beneficiary Token purchaser

     * @param weiAmount Amount of wei contributed

     */

    function _preValidatePurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 weiAmount) internal view {

        super._preValidatePurchase(beneficiary, weiAmount);

        // solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length

        require(_contributions[beneficiary].add(weiAmount) <= getCap(beneficiary), "OS Sale: beneficiary's cap exceeded");

    }

    /**

     * @dev Extend parent behavior to update beneficiary contributions.

     * @param beneficiary Token purchaser

     * @param weiAmount Amount of wei contributed

     */

    function _updatePurchasingState(address beneficiary, uint256 weiAmount) internal {

        super._updatePurchasingState(beneficiary, weiAmount);

        _contributions[beneficiary] = _contributions[beneficiary].add(weiAmount);

    }

}
```